# HTML Customize buttons

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am having challenges to hide specific buttons when a record in MyDql Db is set to 'missed'. 
Please help, here is my code:

**Database Connexion**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM appointment";
$req = $bdd->prepare($sql);
$req->execute();
$events = $req->fetchAll();
```

HTML

> Calendar API Downloaded from
>   http://jamelbaz.com/tutos/integration-de-fullcalendar2-php-mysql

```
<div id="calendar" class="col-centered"> </div> 
<input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Name" >
<input type="text" name="surname" class="form-control" id="surname" placeholder="Surname">
<input type="submit" class="" id="Save" name="1" value="Save changes">
<input type="submit" id="try1" class="button alt" name="2" value="Arrived">
<input type="submit" id="try2" class="button alt" name="3" value="Did not arrived"> //once clicked hide Arrived button
<input type="submit" id="try3 class="button alt" name="3" value="Send email"> //show only if record is set to missed
```

**Backend**

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
element.bind('click', function() {
$('#ModalEdit #name').val(event.name);
$('#ModalEdit #surname.val(event.surname);
},
events: [
<?php
foreach($events as $event): 
?>
title: '<?php echo $event['name'] ?>',
surname: '<?php echo $event['surname']; ?>',
<?php  endforeach;?>
]
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your current ajax based approach is working, Use `$('#your_button_id').prop("disabled", true);` inside your foreach loop. Since this has many buttons, you need to have different button ids for each button to identify separately. you can use a row id or similar id with a name prefix for button ids.

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
element.bind('click', function() {
$('#ModalEdit #name').val(event.name);
$('#ModalEdit #surname.val(event.surname);
},
events: [
<?php
foreach($events as $event): 
   if($event['status']=='missed') {
?>
      $('#your_button_id_or_class').prop("disabled", true);
<?php
   }
?>
title: '<?php echo $event['name']; ?>',
surname: '<?php echo $event['surname']; ?>',
<?php  endforeach;?>
]
});
```